# Class based views (can't follow the book narration)

Tags: django

Example from Django Unleashed by Andrew Pinkham

Django 1.8 (not modern, but I follow the book).

```
class PostList(View):
    template_name = ''

    def get(self, request):
        return render(
            request,
            self.template_name,
            {'post_list': Post.objects.all()})   

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        PostList.as_view(template_name='blog/post_list.html'),
        name='blog_post_list'),
```

In the book:

> 1. Should we wish to change the value of the template_name class attribute, for example, we need only pass it as a named argument to
>    as_view() in the blog_post_list URL pattern.
> 2. However, if the template_name attribute is undefined (we never set it in the class definition), then as_view will ignore it.
> 3. In the event that template_name is unset and the developer forgets to pass it, we should be raising an ImproperlyConfigured exception.

I am keen to understand points 2 and 3 here.

**Point 2:**

```
class PostList(View):
    #template_name = ''

    def get(self, request):


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',
        PostList.as_view(template_name='blog/post_list.html'),
```

I get "PostList() received an invalid keyword 'template_name'. as_view only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class. Whereas in the book I read that nothing will happen ("as_view will ignore it").

Point 3:

```
class PostList(View):
    template_name = ''

    def get(self, request):

url(r'^$',
        PostList.as_view(),
        name='blog_post_list'),
```

I get:

```
"TemplateDoesNotExist at /blog/".
                raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name) ...
▶ Local vars
template_name   ''
```

Well, in the book it should be an ImproperlyConfigured exception.

Has something changed in Django or I just failed to follow the book. Then, how can I imitate the behaviour in points 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the book is wrong about point 2.
When you provide a keyword argument to as_view it's checked to see if the class has that attribute or else throws a TypeError like the one you get.

One other noteworthy point is that you cannot use any of the http_method_names as keyword arguments in as_view. (ie. get, post, put, delete, etc) as those are restricted entry points for class based views in Django. You can however override them in your own view class.

Point 3 I think is a misinterpretation. The book doesn't actually say that it throws the error, instead it tells you should throw an Improperly configured in those cases.

Comment: From the snippet, I believe the view is saying that the view should throw an `ImproperlyConfigured`, not that it actually does.

Django's [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) provides an example of throwing an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception ([source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/92053acbb9160862c3e743a99ed8ccff8d4f8fd6/django/views/generic/base.py#L136)).